# How to quickly create arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab

I've been used to using Python or Matlab where I could create a list like:

```
min = 5;
step = 2;
max = 16;
Range = min:step:max;
```

and Range would be the list [5,7,9,11,13,15].

Is there an equivalently simple way to generate a list like "Range" in C++? So far the simplest thing I can think of is using a for loop but that is comparatively quite tedious.

Comment: So, put it in a function.

Comment: Well the for loop is quite a good idea if you ask me ( would have never come to my mind ).

Comment: [On List Comprehension in C++](http://dev-perspective.blogspot.com/2012/10/on-list-comprehension-in-c.html)

Comment: If you will be doing numerical computations, there are C++ libraries out there that emulate Matlab: [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)[+libigl](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/libigl/matlab-to-eigen.html), you could also have a look at [wikpedia's list of numerical libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C.2B.2B).

Answer (score 5):

C++ doesn't supply such a thing, either in the language or the standard library. I'd write a function template to look (roughly) like something from the standard library, something on this order:

```
namespace stdx {
    template <class FwdIt, class T>
    void iota_n(FwdIt b, size_t count, T val = T(), T step = T(1)) {
        for (; count; --count, ++b, val += step)
            *b = val;
    }
}
```

From there it would look something like this:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
stdx::iota_n(std::back_inserter(numbers), 6, 5, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement that yourself, something like this:

```
std::vector<int> createArray( int min, int max, int step )
{
    std::vector<int> array;
    for( int i = min; i < max; i += step )
    {
        array.push_back( i );
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::generate` for this.

```
std::vector< int > createArray( int min, int max, int step )
{
    std::vector< int > array((max-min)/step);
    int n = min;
    std::generate(array.begin(), array.end(), 
    [&]()
    { 
        int res = n; 
        n+=step;
        return res; 
    });
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such predefine method in C++ for this purpose.
Below code may help you.

```
std::vector<int> createArrayRange( int min, int max, int step )
{
    std::vector<int> array;
    for( int i = min; i < max; i += step )
    {
        array.push_back(i);
    }
    return array
}
```

Or This would be comparatively faster.

```
void createArrayRange( std::vector<int>& array, int min, int max, int step )
{
    for( int i = min; i < max; i += step )
    {
        array.push_back(i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array;
    createArrayRange(array, min, max, step);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No explicit loops needed:

```
vector<int> data(6,2);
data[0] = 5;
std::partial_sum(data.begin(),data.end(),data.begin());
```